# Show a Fragment at a correct position Inside recyclerview on a click

Tags: android, fragment, android-recyclerview

**Problem**
when I add a fragment inside a recycler view on a click event , the fragment is shown but it's not shown on a right position in the recycler view and the reason is that I am not able to put the right position of adapter (which i take using getLayoutPosition method) inside the FragmentTransaction.add() method.

> recyclerViewAdapter.java

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        private TextView adapterPositionText , layoutPositionText , bindviewPositionText;
        private FrameLayout childFragmentContainer;
        private Button showFragmentButton;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            adapterPositionText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_adapter_position);
            layoutPositionText =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_layout_position);
            childFragmentContainer = (FrameLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.child_fragment_container);
            childFragmentContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            showFragmentButton = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.show_fragment_button);
            bindviewPositionText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.binviewHolder_position);
            showFragmentButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(v == showFragmentButton){
                mRecyclerViewItemListener.addFragment( childFragmentContainer ,this.getAdapterPosition());
                Log.d("layout_position : " , ""+getLayoutPosition());
                if(childFragmentContainer.getVisibility() == View.GONE){
                    childFragmentContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

> ParentFragment.java

```
@Override
    public void addFragment(View view, int position) {
        mFragmentData =  mAdapterDataSet.get(position);
        mFragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
        mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        mChildFragment = new ChildFragment();
        mChildFragment.setChildFragData(mFragmentData);
        mFragmentTransaction.add(R.id.child_fragment_container ,mChildFragment, "chaild_fragment");
        mFragmentTransaction.commit();

    }
```

> How to put the position of viewholder(fragment container) while adding
>   the fragment in the fragment container

Comment: I would advise against using a Fragment inside the row of a RecyclerView. I expect it will not behave well when those rows are recycled.

Comment: Please, would you explain why it does not behave well when recycled?

Comment: It sounds like you are thinking of Fragments as Views. They are not. Fragments have their own lifecycles and are managed in a completely different way than Views. Imagine if you add a Fragment in a row of the RecyclerView (so it is attached to the Activity), and then the row is recycled. What happens to the Fragment? What if you try to attach another Fragment when you bind the old row view to a new position? What about if you rotate the device and the system recreates and reattaches Fragments for you? RecyclerView is going to build new rows, so how can they be reattached properly?

Comment: Managing this properly is going to be exceedingly difficult. The only adapter-based View that actually does something like this is ViewPager, and ViewPager actually doesn't recycle anything. Also, all of your rows have a View with ID `R.id.child_fragment_container `, so when you call `fragmentTransaction.add()` with this ID, there are multiple views on screen with this ID, and the FragmentManager has no way to know which one should hold the Fragment. Bottom line, I don't see any way to make this work in any sane manner.

Comment: Ok , I got your points and thank for your help ... @Karakuri